# Facebook can't scrape some of my pages, and some can. WEIRD

Tags: php, html, facebook, wordpress, share

I have the weirdest issue ever...  well maybe not ever but it is weird.

So I want to have a custom share on my website and now I am just testing all my links.

When using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
I get positive for this: 
http://komentiraj.ba/misimovic-se-oprasta-od-reprezentacije/

and I don't get anything for let's say 
/recep-tayyip-erdogan-izabran-je-za-12-predsjednika-turske/

Both have all:og meta tags.

What could go wrong?

Comment: You have to fix the errors that the object debugger is telling you about.

Comment: That's the thing I already have them in http://screencast.com/t/oeQu0Yzu3E

Comment: Yea - sorry. The error was not about those tags (older errors). Take a look at the debugger - it's complaining about some time parameter - all the errors can be seen in the debugger.

Comment: there is no time parameter..  now that post from the first example is working.. but if I test another one http://screencast.com/t/luXhzQRA  that does not work.. and it says it scrapped 2 hours ago..  how do i make facebook to scrape now since I changed my parameters ?

Comment: You need to click "Fetch new scrape information". The fact that there is no time parameter may be the problem. Click that "new scrape" button to see a more updated version of your page in the debugger.

Comment: Man tried that too :) http://screencast.com/t/mlUmiiUz  another problem comes up

Comment: Yes - you have to fix **all** of the problems that it tells you about. Sometimes one error is hiding another - just keep fixing what it tells you till you get the results you want. Currently it's complaining about the value you gave for `og:title` and also a connection issue - the connection issue could be because you are developing the site right now and perhaps the file was still uploading when you ran the test. Just keep re-running the debugger fetching new scrape information.

Comment: they seem to be popping up randomly now ...  I don't need to create app id and register it on fb right as an app ?